# Mui custom yearCalendar inner text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

As I want to custom the inner text in Mui `@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.2.1"`,I found that the slots of the slots of `MobileDatePicker` only have the `day` name

how can I specify the year calendar and render the 'Now' text instead of current year?

I have already accomplish the components, but how can I avoid the format check?

the demo is below

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-dewdney-8vdptd?file=/demo.tsx